# Backticks versus real quote marks

Tags: symbols, unicode, syntax

So, I'm a Mac user, and a little bit of a type nut (probably not compared to many users on here, though! :P)

I've been happily typing emdashes and curly-quotes on my keyboard for years, and years: `⌥⇧-`, `⌥[` / `⌥⇧[` … you get the idea. Now, LaTeX has been pretty wonderful so far, but I've been studiously avoiding junk like `\wedge` or `---` or ``` `` ``` where just typing the damn Unicode character would work perfectly fine *(Hon.m [unicode-math](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math)!)* … but I'm definitely getting the impression that that's going against the grain in this community, and I want to write what's perceived as clean, idiomatic code, so …

---

Is there any typesetting benefit or purpose to using ``` `` ``` instead of `“`, and similar LaTeX conventions, in the source-code to your LaTeX document?

Comment: Take a look at `csquotes` it will put quotes according to the currently active language and you can choose witch style to use per language. Pretty cool.

Comment: With respect to using the unicode char or the LaTeX thing, it will be the same for pdflatex under the hood

Comment: as long as you have specified `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and the character you are typing is defined, or if you are using xelatex or lualatex, then the input forms are converted to a common form before being typeset, so use whichever is easiest

Comment: @Johannes_B am I to understand that David's answer is wrong, then? i.e. `csquotes` and similar *only* replace `` etc, and won't work if I'm using “these” throughout my document?

Comment: clearly my comment can't be wrong:-)  csquotes addresses a different issue: you don't use the quote characters at all and use tex command markup to mark the quotation, then that can use high quotes or German style low commas or french guillemets or whatever according to the document settings

Comment: No, not wrong. With csquotes you say `\enquote{this text is enquoted}` and the package decides what to place.

Comment: If what you're doing works well for you, then by all means keep doing it. Which keyboard and language settings have you enabled, by the way? Various keyboard combinations that may work with a US-layout keyboard (just to give an example) may be unusable with other layouts. For sure, don't assume that just because the combination [Option]-[5] produces an `∞` symbol on a US-style keyboard, the same symbol will appear if this combination is pressed and a German, French, Italian, Spanish, etc keyboard layout is in use.

Comment: Precisely because of the pronounced differences in keyboard layouts, it's much easier on this site to write `\infty` to indicate that `∞` needs to be produced. The alternative would be having to say, "hit [Option]-[5] on a US keyboard, [Option]-[,] on a German keyboard," etc. There must be dozens and dozens of keyboard layouts...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have unicode input correctly declared either via

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

or using xelatex or lualatex then  ``` `` ``` will ligature to “ and produce identical output.

So the pros and cons are all about the human interface to editing, not about latex.

Most latex users use ascii input as they have been using it for a long time, but even now it has some advantages as many people learn (or copy what they did before) by viewing the source, for most people, with most keyboards it does not require any instruction to know how to type ``` `` ``` or `\infty` but it may not be so clear (and the instructions will be very system and locale specific) how to type `“` or `∞`.

For example I did not recognise your `⌥⇧-` at all but the first character is U+2325 which is OPTION KEY which I vaguely remember being the name of one of the modifier keys on a Mac keyboard.